# Hibernate generates wrong insert statement for DB2

Tags: java, hibernate, db2

I'm using hibernate with DB2 database. When I'm running spring batch job I have following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into "PERSON" (id, first_name, last_name) values (default, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

When I paste query from log to IBM Data Studio I see that query is seems to lack quotes on field names. The valid statement would be

```
insert into "PERSON" ("id", "first_name", "last_name") values (default, 'John122', 'Doe21')
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I would try to fight Hibernate. Using quoted identifiers is almost always a bad idea to start with. Just create your table without quoting any of the column names and everything will work just fine

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the tip. I've created table using IBM Data Studio and it generated those quotes. When I recreated table manually without quotes, everything seems to run normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between the following two statements:

`create table Person (
id integer, 
first_name vargraphic(80), 
last_name vargraphic(80)
);`

and

`create table "Person" (
"id" integer,
"first_name" vargraphic(80), 
"last_name" vargraphic(80)
);`

The first statement creates the table PERSON, with column ID, FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME (mind the uppercase!). The second statement creates the table Person with the columns id, first_name and last_name.

It seems that you created your table with the second definition, but are trying to update it with a statement correct for the first table definition.

TL;DR: DB2 always creates all table and column names in uppercase, unless the names are between (double) quotes.

Comment: Note that, even though it reports them as "uppercase", the system will _ignore_ casing for all subsequent statements.

Comment: Thanks. Didnt knew this case